# Running 2 Meteor.js apps on the same computer causes error with npm packages

Tags: macos, node.js, meteor, npm

If I launch the first meteor project which uses npm packages via the `meteor-npm` package, followed by a second meteor project using the `meteor-npm` package, the first meteor project will suddenly have problem finding the npm packages right after the second meteor server has finished deploying:

```
Error: Can't find npm module 'mysql'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'npm' package?
```

Restarting the first meteor server, the server output will show

```
npm: updating npm dependencies -- mysql...
```

And things will start working.

This problem happens everytime I have 2 meteor 0.7 servers running at the same time on the same system. Is there some problem with the setup/permissions of the npm packages?